# Accessing google.maps namespace in vue3 vite application

Tags: typescript, google-maps, vuejs3, vite

I have a Vue3 typescript application using Vite and Yarn. I am using a Google Maps dependency called `vue3-google-map`. Google maps is now working in a simple Map component:

```
<template>
  <GoogleMap
    id="map"
    ref="mapRef"
    :api-key="Backbone.mapSettings.key"
    :center="Backbone.mapSettings.center"
    :zoom="Backbone.mapSettings.zoom"

    style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
  />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { GoogleMap } from 'vue3-google-map';

let gmap: google.maps.Map | null = null;
let mapRef = ref<google.maps.Map | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
    initMap();
});

function initMap() {
    watch(() => (mapRef.value as any)?.ready as any,    (x) => {
        gmap = (mapRef.value as any).map;
    });
}

</script>>
```

Now I need to access the google.maps namespace in another typescript file to define a variable:

```
export default class MapSettings {
    public center: google.maps.LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.26392, 9.501785);
}
```

The linter don´t warns about any problems. But when the app is compiled in the browser I get:

```
MapSettings.ts:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at <instance_members_initializer> (MapSettings.ts:6:38)
    at new MapSettings (MapSettings.ts:3:1)
```

It is not accessiable via window.google either. If I create a constructor with a setTimeout for 1 second, I am able to access the google.maps namespace. I guess this proves that the google namespace is lazyloaded after the   <GoogleMap ... element in the template has been intialized.

I´ve tried adding @types/google.maps to the project but that did not help.
I can however import google maps in index.html to make it work:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"></script>
```

But this is of course wrong and I also get a console warning:

```
Google Maps already loaded outside @googlemaps/js-api-loader.This may result in undesirable behavior as options and script parameters may not match.
```

I also tried another vue3 google maps library (`vue3-google-maps`), but the problem is the same.

So how do you access the google namespace in typescript when it is indirectly used by a third party component?

Comment: Any code containing `google.maps...` will trigger this error if the code is ran before the API has finished loaded. Standard way with the JS API is to use the `callback` parameter the API provides. With the loader, I don't know, but there must be something similar.